# jQuery - If screen is less than specified width (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

How can I make an alert popup if the width of the page is less than `1200px`, and made responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "also made responsive"? Do you want to detect support for media queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like the [breakpoints](https://github.com/eikes/breakpoints) module. Then you setup a breakpoint to trigger at 1200px and show a dialog and either add a css class that changes the layout, or use straight javascript to make the changes.

```
breakpoints(1200, function(oldPoint, newPoint) {
  alert('The screen width just changed');
});
```

if you just wanted native jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width < 1200){
    alert('Your screen is too small');
  }
});
```

---

For completeness, heres the CSS media query (still doesn't take care of the alert, but can help with making the website "responsive").

```
/* some normal style */
.myclass {
  font-size: 22pt;
}

/* alter the style when the screen's smaller */
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .myclass {
    font-size: 18pt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For future Googlers, a 2019 solution is to use JavaScript's `window​.match​Media()`. It is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) in all major browsers and IE 10 onwards.

You can use it like this:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) {
    // functionality for screens smaller than 1200px
}
```

To make this responsive, you just need to wrap it in a `resize` function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 1200px)').matches) {
        // functionality for screens smaller than 1200px
    }
});
```

This is arguably the most easiest way to check a screen size and it doesn't bloat the code.

Check the Mozilla docs about [match​Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to learn more and this one for more info on [Testing media queries programmatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries).